# Java not running with Eclipse, editing eclipse.ini gives error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I recently installed the latest version of the Android SDK which includes Eclipse. Upon trying to run Eclipse, I first came up with the error

`A Java Runtime Environment or Java Development Kit must be available...`

as many other users have found. I realized that I had incorrectly installed Java, and fixed that problem. That error message no longer appears. However, I am now getting the message:

`Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll`

I looked up the issue and found that many people suggest editing the eclipse.ini file to include a -vm argument. I have tried this, but I cannot save the file. Whenever I try, I receive an error message saying `Access is denied.`

I am running Windows 8. Both Eclipse and Java are 64-bit. I am the sole administrator on the computer. If you can provide me with any ideas how to fix my problem, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Is Eclipse running while you try to edit the file?

Comment: run eclipse as administrator, ie right click and select `run as administrator` and check

Comment: Anything in "Program Files (x86)" is 32-bit.  If your Eclipse is actually 64-bit, that would explain why you saw the failure to load the .dll.  Try a 32-bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put eclipse into the "Program Files" folder. By default, eclipse wants to write into the sub directories of the installation, which does not work at that location. It would also explain your problems editing the ini file.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8, Drive C:\ is system drive, only administrator user can modify its contents. It is not recommended to put Eclipse in this location, but if want just run it, you can right click on eclipse.exe then choose **run as Administrator**, a popup may appear to confirm your decision to run this program, choose option '**yes**'.